# RemoteNotification Dict has changed and CKNotification Dict is different now

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit, xcode7

I hope someone can guide me...I know Swift 2.0/ Xcode 7 still in beta but I need to convert my code...
Here is my code...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        let notification:CKNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo)
        //application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        if (notification.notificationType == CKNotificationType.Query) {
            let queryNotification = notification as! CKQueryNotification
            let recordID = queryNotification.recordID
            receivedRecord = recordID
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("updateDatabase", object: nil)
        }
    }
```

So the expected Dict for CKNotification has changed to [String:NSObject] -> before was [NSObject:AnyObject] which conformed to the returned Dict! and the returned Dict from the function(didReceiveRemoteNotification) is: [NSObject : AnyObject]

Taken from Xcode 7 -> public convenience init(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary notificationDictionary: [String : NSObject])

Taken from Xcode 6.4 -> convenience init!(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary notificationDictionary: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)

So, my question is, how could I convert this or do I miss something obvious? Might this be a bug?

Thanks for any guidance/ help...

Comment: My tip for updating methods whose signature has changed: don't modify the one you have in place, instead, start typing the method call on another line and Xcode will auto-suggest the new signature; then you just have to adapt and edit.

Comment: I tried that but there was no suggestion from Xcode in that case, I already tried a lot and asking here was the last option....

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
if let userInfo = userInfo as? [String: NSObject] {
    let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo)
    ...
    ...
}
```